# Assigning Creatives to Placements in DFA/DCM Reporting and Trafficking API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, double-click-advertising, google-reporting-trafficking-api

Yo. I'm implementing some stuff in the DFA/DCM Reporting and Trafficking API using the Google API PHP Client Library. So far I've added creatives to my campaigns, but I'm trying to figure out where I can add these creatives to a campaign's placements.

I haven't seen anything regarding adding creatives to placements or the other way around in the documentation, just that I can add Creatives to Campaigns as-is. Any hints? Tips?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, wow. You just insert the placement and it'll auto-match them, it looks like. Welp.